# Kotlin: complaining about "Property 'disabled_rules' is deprecated" in '.editorconfig' files

Tags: kotlin, editorconfig, spotless

New to Kotlin.
Notice a bunch

```
Property 'disabled_rules' is deprecated: Rename property 'disabled_rules' to 'ktlint_disabled_rules' in all '.editorconfig' files.
```

I donot have a '.editorconfig' file under repo root.

What is causing this? Should I generate a `.editorconfig` file myself? If so, how do I generate that?

I created .editorconfig by exporting from IDE
[image]

But no 'disabled_rules' was found, how and where should I add it to this file?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created `.editorconfig` myself file and it didn't work initially.

Make sure you Enable EditorConfig support in IDE.

For Android Studio it is at Settings → Editor → Code Style → Enable EditorConfig support.

After checking this, it worked for me.